# My 8-year-old daughter soils her pants daily. What can I do?

Tags: middle-childhood, encopresis

My 8-year-old daughter is soiling her pants daily and couldn't care less about the whole situation with I am just about out of patience.

She is collected daily from school with soiled pants and has been sitting in it for hours and she absolutely smells of poo and her school shorts are stuck to her skin and she couldn't care less. When she is at home on the weekend she is constantly changing her soiled underpants and pants at least 6 or more a day. 
She also refuses to wipe her bottom. She has a poo, gets up and goes.

I have been to the doctor who has ruled out any medical conditions making her do this and also when we were at the doctors she was clenching so hard to not go and do her poo she was shaking. The doctor believes it is complete laziness causing the problem, as if she had that much control over holding it in, there is no medical reason she can't do it in the toilet.

I'm after any suggestions as if this keeps going on at school she is going to be bullied and made fun of.

Comment: If you have a doctor who says "this is complete laziness," you may want to seek a second opinion. Perhaps there isn't a _physical_ medical reason, but there may be a _mental_ medical reason, and a good medical professional should help you find the appropriate resources. You may want to read through other questions on the site about [tag:encopresis].

Comment: Who washes her underpants? And had there ever been a time, where she did use the toilet properly? If so, when and why did it change again? And if not, could you maybe add some details about her toilet training (when and how)?

Answer (score 3):

Have you spoken to more than one doctor or just the one? Sometimes if you go to a second doctor they might have another idea as to what might be wrong.

If a second doctor doesn't find anything medically wrong I'd consider taking her to a therapist - laziness isn't any kind of diagnosis, and pooping in her pants and not being bothered seems to me like unusual behavior at 8 years old.